# Генерация 3-х мерного лабиринта

Tags: алгоритм

Я бы хотел реализовать генерацию трехмерного лабиринта, что-то вроде этого

[image: картинка]

Ничего путного по этой теме найти не удалось. Есть у кого идеи на эту тему?

Comment: Как то нет желания переходить на неизвестные ссылки. Опишите  что это за лабиринт и какие наработки у вас уже есть. Исходя из этого появится возможность Вам помочь. К тому же ссылки извне часто "умирают" - вопрос будет просто хламом и никому от этого пользы не будет.

Comment: это просто картинка. Ну смотрите есть 2-х мерные лабиринты и алгоритмов их генерации полно: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm а есть 2-х мерные в виде куба, наработок нет никаких, делал когда-то давно 2-мерный лабиринт методом Recursive backtracker. Поищите в гугле 3d maze puzzle, там есть картинки головоломок с такими вот лабиринтами.

Comment: Ну так алгоритмы разве не те же?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для начала, определимся с тем, что же такое лабиринт, т.е. дадим первое определение лабиринта, которое впоследствии мы чуть-чуть модифицируем. Я буду рассматривать двумерный случай. Трёхмерный во всех его вариациях строится ровно так же.

**Определение**. Лабиринтом на плоскости будем называть связный неориентированный граф без петель, у каждой вершины которого не более 4 ребёр.

Довольно легко провести аналогию решётки-лабиринта *nxm* и лабиринта. Как это сделать? Достаточно рассмотреть клетку и заметить, что у каждой клетки есть 4 соседа (не берём граничные случаи):

[image: Пример решётки и соседей клетки]

Теперь можно убрать, например, одного соседа. Обычная ситуация в лабиринте:

[image: Пример решётки и соседей клетки]

Каждую клетку можно ассоциировать с вершиной. Наличие соседа - связывать с ребром. В таком случае, довольно очевидно, что определение более или менее корректное. С первого взгляда непонятно: для каждого ли лабиринта можно подобрать решётку-лабиринт, ровно как и наоборот. Здесь уже необходимо строгое доказательство, которое приводить смысла много не имеет.

Вообще говоря, для порождения самого лабиринта, строить граф в явном виде не обязательно. Я лишь заострил внимание на этом, дабы дать волю Вашей фантазии. Построение графа может быть полезно при более детальном изучении вопроса. Вам может быть важно, чтобы лабиринт обладал какими-нибудь свойствами. Может быть Вам захочется ввести некую "плотность" или разветвлённость лабиринта. В таком случае на помощь могут прийти именно графы.

**Определение**. Границей решётки или просто границей назовём такую вершину, координата которой на решётке равна: (x, m), или (n,x), или (1,x), или (n,x), где х -- любое число из промежутков [1,n] или [1,m].

Теперь же, перейдём к генерации лабиринта. Сделаем это так. Зададим матрицу *nxm*. Выберем одну точку на одной из границ. После этого запустим из этой точки [обход в глубину](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) в пределах решётки.

Для каждой точки лабиринта будем по очереди выбирать каждое из 4х направлений и случайным образом, с вероятность *p*, принимать решение, есть ли проход в этом направлении или его нет. Будем его выполнять до тех пор, пока суммарное количество точек на границе будет не более *k*. Как только это произойдёт, мы прекращаем наше выполнение действий.

Делая действия таким образом, можно получить очень неравномерный лабиринт. Поэтому можно критерий останова чуть-чуть изменить. Будем его выполнять процесс до тех пор, пока суммарное количество точек на границе будет не более *k* и на каждой из границ (всего границы, разумеется, 4), будет не менее *k_i* точек.

Теперь нам нужно выбрать выбрать начало и конец. Можно, конечно, взять любые 2 точки на границе, но в таком случае, может случиться, что путь от начала в конец окажется тривиальным (т.е. слишком простым и коротким). Для того, чтобы этого избежать, следует выбирать начальную и конечную точки на расстоянии друг от друга не менее чем *d*.

Таким образом мы построили алгоритм генерации лабиринта с параметрами: *k*, *k_i* (4 шт), *p*, *d*.

Советую обратить внимание на такую вещь как [теория перколяции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8). В этой теории реализуется процесс, который я описал выше.

У меня валяются три реализации перколяционного процесса на питоне, матлабе и плюсах. Вы можете на них взгялнуть здесь: [1](https://bitbucket.org/hedgehogues_repo/numerical-analysis.-percolation-matlab), [2](https://bitbucket.org/hedgehogues_repo/numerical-analysis.-percolation-c), [3](https://bitbucket.org/hedgehogues_repo/numerical-analysis.-percolation-python)

Comment: не ясно откуда "без петель" условие. Не все 2D алгоритмы на 3D переносятся.

Comment: @jfs данный алгоритм переносится легко. В чем непонятки с мигрированием в 3D? Без петель связано с тем, что при отображении графа на решётку, возникнет вопрос, во что переходить петле?

Comment: *"Трёхмерный во всех его вариациях строится ровно так же"* можно воспринять что любой 2D алгоритм в 3D переносится легко (что не так). Под "без петель" я [неверно] воспринял "без циклов" (перевёл как cycle а нужно было как loop). Цикл длины один (петля, self-loop) действительно для простых лабиринтов смысла не имеют и они обычно не упоминаются.

Comment: @jfs те модификации построения лабиринтов, которые я описал, построить несложно для размерности n. Кроме того, автор хочет построить не 3х мерный лабиринт, а 6 двумерных, которые соединяются по границам друг с другом. Это также легко сделать. Я имел ввиду именно это, написав фразу  
*"Трёхмерный во всех его вариациях строится ровно так же"*

Comment: да я на самом деле уже разобрался, просто не было ответа, чтобы закрыть вопрос. я в математике не силен, особенно в теории графов, поэтому не был уверен что из 2д в 3д получится перенести. Сделал реализацию на c# и рисую в юнити, использовал метод recursive backtracker, если кому интересно будет, могу на гит закинуть.

Comment: @JacksonFaller если нужно будет что-то по математике в этой части, можешь писать hedgehogues@bk.ru

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Comment: @JacksonFaller если нашли решение, то опубликуйте как свой ответ, если его ещё не опубликовали другие. Это явно приветствуется https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое что может придти в голову, это генерировать 3 мерный массив через Random(), если писать на Java.

```
        int n = 10;

        int[][][] arr = new int[n][n][n];

        for (int i=0; i<n; i++){

            for (int j=0; j<n; j++){

                for (int k=0; k<n; k++){

                    Random random = new Random();
                    Integer r = random.nextInt(2);
                    if (r != 0) {
                        arr[i][j][k] = 1;
                    }else{
                        arr[i][j][k] = 0;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

Если один, то есть проход, иначе нет прохода. На счет отрисовки его в 3d модели зависит от того на чем вы пишите, на Java можно использовать jPCT.

Comment: Это не лабиринт, а просто кубик с непроходимыми клетками. Путь в лабиринте должен быть связным и, скорее всего, с единственным входом и единственным выходом.

Comment: Согласен, тогда в начале можно сгенерировать рандомный путь например от ячейки [0][0][0] до ячейки [n-1][n-1][n-1].Случайно выбирается один путь из 6(вверх, вниз, вправо, влево, вперед, назад), естественно с учетом границ массива и идем до тех пор пока мы не окажемся в последней ячейки, это будет гарантировать, что в лабиринте есть выход, а после через тот же рандом путаем его, как в алгоритме выше, при этом не перекрывая ячейки правильного пути.